# Swift Compiler errors when trying to return a Sqlite.swift query as an array

Tags: arrays, sqlite.swift

Trying to get query results into an array. The example from the documentation shows this working...

```
let statement = try db.prepare(query)
var results = Array(statement)
```

...however when I try to compile this I get...

```
Ambiguous use of 'init'
```

... for the Array(statement)

If I change to this...

```
let statement = try db.prepare(query)
var results = Array<SQLite.Row>(statement)
```

I get this error...

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Check my answer, and let me know if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the rows to put them into an array:

```
for statement in try db.prepare(query) {
    yourArray.append(statement)
}
```